# how to get the first element in the parenthesis

Tags: awk, sed

I have data like in the file below and I want to extract the first value inside the parenthesis of Test accuracies.

```
Intent i1

Test accuracies:
(0.90, 1.0, 0.8095238095238095, 0.8947368421052632)
Test average id : 1.0446857355e-06
Test average ood : 0.0693251593621
ood_train: 173
ood_test: 42
ood_val: 113

Intent i2

Test accuracies:
(0.92, 1.0, 0.8571428571428571, 0.923076923076923)
Test average id entropy: 8.82025156164e-06
Test average ood entropy: 0.0688835002447
ood_train: 173
ood_test: 42
ood_val: 113

Intent i3

Test accuracies:
(0.93, 1.0, 0.8095238095238095, 0.8947368421052632)
Test average id entropy: 2.35249270365e-07
Test average ood entropy: 0.0534607628718
ood_train: 173
ood_test: 42
ood_val: 113
```

I want to print the first entry after the parenthesis that appears after "Test accuracies" like below:

```
0.90
0.92
0.93
```

I was trying to use this command but I can't get there in one step

```
awk -F"[()]" '{print $2}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `grep`, you may use a PCRE regex like

```
grep -Poz 'Test accuracies:\R\(\K\d[\d.]*' file.txt > outfile.txt
```

**Details**

- `-Poz` - `P` enables the PCRE regex syntax, `o` turns on the output match mode and `z` allows matching text across line breaks (*Treat input and output data as sequences of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline*, see [GNU `grep` docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Other-Options)).
- `Test accuracies:` -   a literal substring
- `\R` - any line break sequence (CR, LF or CRLF)
- `\(` - a `(` char (must be escaped in a PCRE pattern)
- `\K` - match [reset operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) that discards the text matched so far
- `\d` - a digit
- `[\d.]*` - 0 or more digit or `.` chars.

You may use `awk` like this:

```
awk -F'[(),]' '/^Test accuracies:$/{getline; print $2; }' file.txt > outfile.txt
```

See [demo online](https://ideone.com/8myWP3)

Here,

- `-F'[(),]'` sets field separator to `(`, `)` and `,`
- `/^Test accuracies:$/` matches the whole line  with `Test accuracies:` text on it
- Once that line is found, `getline` reads the next line
- `print $2` prints Field 2 contents.

Answer (score 1):

[`pcregrep`](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcregrep.html) is quite a powerful tool that supports PCRE with multi-line match mode which is not used that regularly. You could just do

```
pcregrep -oM 'Test accuracies:\n\(\K([^,]+)' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk -v RS='Test accuracies:\n\\(' -F, 'NR>1{print $1}' file
```

`RS` is the record separator set to match across 2 lines the `Test accuracies:` pattern and on the next line the parenthesis `(`.

`-F,` sets the field separator to a comma and allows to get the first field right after the parenthesis.

According to the input file, this needs to be done after first record `NR>1`.

Answer (score 0):

The following line will work in your above example:

```
awk -F "[(, )]*" '/\(/&&/\)/{print $2}'
```

A more robust case would be:

```
awk 'n=index($0,"("){print substr($0,n+1,index($0,",")-n-1)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

To capture the name of the data block, as well, try

```
awk -F"[(,]" '/^Intent/ {x=$0} /^\(/ {print x "\t" $2; x=""}' file
```

This returns

```
Intent i1   0.90
Intent i2   0.92
Intent i3   0.93
```